# How can I check if an object has an empty value on a key?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, lodash

I am working on a form validation and I need to check when there is an empty value.

So far the validation goes like this:

```
const areFieldsFilledOut = () => {
    if (
      (size(startupThirdStepForm) === 9 &&
        !has(startupThirdStepForm, 'middleName')) ||
      size(startupThirdStepForm) === 10
    ) {
      stepThreeCardSelectedActionHandler(true);
      return false;
    }
    if (
      has(startupThirdStepForm.middleName) &&
      !startupThirdStepForm.middleName.length
    ) {
      stepThreeCardSelectedActionHandler(true);
      return false;
    }

    return 'disabled';
  };
```

That middle name thing is just something that is not required.
The object could have around 15 keys maximum. So all I want to do with `lodash` -hopefully- is one more validation like this:
(pseudo code)

```
    if (
       startupThirdStepForm has any key with an empty value
    ) {
      stepThreeCardSelectedActionHandler(false);
      return true;
    }
```

`startupThirdStepForm` is the object containing what I need to check. It is an empty object but the keys/values are created dynamically.

So I need to return `true` like in the pseudo code above, when there is something like this:

```
startupThirdStepForm: { key1: 'I have a value', key2: '' }
```

And return `false` when every key has a proper value, not an empty one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `_.some()` to iterate the object's property, and check if a value is an empty string with `_.isEqual()`.

```js
const optional = ['middle']
const startupThirdStepForm = { key1: 'I have a value', key2: '', middle: '' }

const result = _.some(_.omit(startupThirdStepForm, optional), _.partial(_.isEqual, ''))

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

And the same idea with lodash/fp:

```js
const fn = optional => _.flow(
  _.omit(optional),
  _.some(_.isEqual(''))
)

const optional = ['middle']

const withoutOptional = fn(optional)

console.log(withoutOptional({ key1: 'I have a value', key2: '' })) // true
console.log(withoutOptional({ key1: 'I have a value', middle: '' })) // false
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```

Comment: How can I ignore one specific key? I would like to ignore `middle` since it is not a required field.

Comment: You can use `_.omit()` to remove it for the check. I'll update the examples.

Answer (score 1):

If it's only about own properties you can use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to get every property value as an array and then use `.some` to check if any of them are empty:

```
if (Object.values(startupThirdStepForm).some(v => v === '')) {

}
```